# Hybrid Remote on Mobile SDK 5+: how to handle cordova.js on iOS?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, cordova

I'm currently making the move from MobileSDK 4.x to 5.2 for a hybrid remote app with Android and iOS builds, and I need some help on using `cordova.js` on iOS.  I'm observing that `cordova.js` is not loading from localhost, and any Javascript that references the variable `cordova` fails.  What I've figured out so far from the SDK Docs:

1. in Chap 9, section "Developing Hybrid Remote Apps," is the traditional advice, "For hybrid remote applications, you are no longer required to host `cordova.js` or any plug-ins on the server. Instead, you can include `cordova.js` as`https://localhost/cordova.js` in your HTML source."  This is what we've always done (and are currently doing).
2. Also in Chap 9, very next section, "Using localhost in Hybrid Remote Apps for iOS," it states, "Beginning with version 5.0, Mobile SDK follows Apple’s mandate and deprecates the UIWebView class in favor of WKWebView....  WKWebView enforces a stricter content security protocol than its predecessor and does not support localhost."  It goes on to show how to switch back to UIWebView.  Since the only local file I need is `cordova.js`, I'd rather not do this.
3. Also in Chap 9, in the section "Accessing the Salesforce API with Force.js," are instructions for putting `cordova.js` into a static resource, but no mention is made where to get `cordova.js`.

To be clear - if all we need "locally" in a remote hybrid app under iOS is `cordova.js`, **is there no other provision** than switching back to UIWebView or serving `cordova.js` from the server (i.e., from a static resource)?  I feel like I'm missing something here... the change notes from 5.1 state, "We’ve replaced our custom WKWebViewEngine plug-in with Cordova's WKWebViewEngine plug-in" which implies Cordova should work with WKWebViewEngine?

If we do need to serve `cordova.js` from a static resource, **which version do I use?**  I searched the generated project code for `cordova.js`, and found 4 different versions (by checksum); looking at the header of each file, it looks like there's an iOS version, two Android versions, and even a Node version (part of phonegap-plugin-push).  Do I need some type of client side logic to dynamically include the correct `cordova.js`?  What happens the next time we update the MobileSDK and there's a new version of `cordova.js`?  Older app versions will get the newer `cordova.js`.﻿